# Dft to evaluate Fourier coefficients

Tags: fourier-analysis, coefficients

Use the DFT to evaluate the N Fourier coefficients cs of fp(t), derived by sampling the
following periodic functions: (a) fp(t) = cos^2(t) and (b) fp(t) with unit cell φ(t) = rect(t) and
period ∆t = 3. Employ lists of N = 2^5 elements.

I've already tried:
a)

`Table [z, 2^5]`, where z is:
`z = FourierCoefficient[Cos[t]^2, t, n]`

b)

```
p = FourierCoefficient [UnitBox [t], t, s, FourierParameters -> {1, -2 π/Δt}, 
Assumptions -> -Δt/2 ⩽ t <=  Δt/2 && Δt ⩾ 1]
Δt = 3;
Table [p, 2^5]
```

But I don't know if that's right.

Comment: Have you seen `Fourier[]` already?

Answer (score 2):

To check if the Fourier coef. are correct, you can build the Fourier series and check if it gives the original function. For your first example:

```
Clear[fc, f];
fc[n_] = FourierCoefficient[Cos[t]^2, t, n]
```

[image]

There a only a finite number of coefs. Further, as the original function is even, we only need `Cos` terms (the same coefs could have been obtained by `FourierCosCoefficent`). Therefore we obtain the series and plot it by:

```
f[t_] = Sum[fc[n] Cos[n t], {n, -2, 2}];
Plot[{f[t], Cos[t]^2}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Both function are identical.

The second example is a bit more complicated. It has an infinite number of coefs and the period is different from 2 Pi. The description is not too clear, I assume a function is given that is 1 from -0.5..0.5 and otherwise 0 with a period of 3. To make things simple we first create a function with period 2Pi and scale it at the end. Toward this end we use not `UnitBox[t]` but `UnitBox[t 1.5/Pi]`. The coefs are:

```
Clear[fc, f1,f];
fc[s_] = FourierCoefficient[UnitBox[t 1.5/Pi], t, s]
```

[image]

You see, there are an infinite number of coefs this time. The Fourier series is (we choose nmax=20 as an example. Play with it to see the effect):

```
nmax = 20;
f1[t_] = Sum[fc[n] Cos[n t], {n, -nmax, nmax}];
```

Now we have a function with period 2Pi. To scale it to 3 and plot the new function:

```
f[t_] = f1[t  Pi/1.5];
Plot[{f[t], UnitBox[Mod[t, 2.5]]}, {t, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]