# Fourier and Table to evaluate coefficients

Tags: fourier-analysis

How can I use the DFT to evaluate the N Fourier coefficients using `Fourier[]` and `Table`?

Where (N=2^5, it is the number of elements) is c =1/√N Fourier[f]

My functions are:
(a) fp(t) = cos^2(t)
(b) fp(t) with unit cell φ(t) = rect(t) and period ∆t = 3, where rect is in Mathematica the function known as UnitBox [t].

Comment: We need additional information (and best if you try some Mathematica code).  Mathematica uses `N` as an internal function., e.g., `N[expr]`
gives the numerical value of expr.  My guess, you want "N" as a list of coefficients. Anyone answering will also need to know what you mean by: cos2(t),  φ(t), and rect(t).  These don't stand a constructs within Mathematica.

Comment: Please follow this [guide](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and improve your post; especially, the problem you are facing would be clearer for the community if you could format your math neatly, better than which given as a code implementation as well. I'll edit the post according to my understanding, but if it does not reflect your original intention, do feel free to roll it back.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dft to evaluate Fourier coefficients](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240793/dft-to-evaluate-fourier-coefficients)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
f[t_] := fp(t);(*Cos[t]^2*)
n = 26;
tm = N[Range[n - 1]]/n;
fm = Map[f, tm];
coefs = FourierDST[fm, 1]/Sqrt[n/2]
coefc = FourierDCT[fm, 1]/Sqrt[n/2]
```