# Dft on rectangular function

Tags: fourier-analysis, code-review

Our function $rect(t)$ has a period of Δt = 3, but we want to turn it into a periodic function in order to extract the Fourier coefficients.

I've done it this way and it's right, but I don't understand it:

```
t6 = 3/2^5* Table[(r - 1), {r, 1, 2^5}]
t7 = (HeavisidePi[t6] + HeavisidePi[t6-3]) 

1/Sqrt[32] Fourier[t7]
```

I would appreciate if someone can explain it to me or knows and easier way to do it.

Comment: I believe you have posted several questions on the same topic, it would be easier for the community to recognize your effort and for helpers to navigate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dft to evaluate Fourier coefficients](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240793/dft-to-evaluate-fourier-coefficients)